# navigation burger icon blinks repeatedly when scrolling down/up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navigation

I wanted a code where the burger icon changes color dynamically to accommodate the either black part/section of the site and the white. Its initally 3 spans of white and the js code is almost good and proper but it keeps blinking when its in the white section and flickers between red and white.

js

```
var top2 = $('#section2').offset().top; //white background
var top3 = $('#section3').offset().top;
var top4 = $('#section4').offset().top; //white background
var top5 = $('#section5').offset().top;


$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
  var $nav = $("#toggle .span");
  if (scrollPos >= top2 && scrollPos <= top3) {
    $nav.toggleClass('scrolled');
  } else if (scrollPos >= top4 && scrollPos <= top5) {
    $nav.toggleClass('scrolled');
  } else {
    $nav.removeClass('scrolled');
  }
});
```

css with media query for the insert of the js class  #toggle .span.scrolled

```
 #toggle {
      position: fixed;
      right: 20px;
      top: 14px;
      z-index: 999;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      cursor: pointer;
      float: right;
      /* transition: all 0.3s ease-out; */
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
    }

    #toggle .span {
      height: 3px;
      background: #fff;
      /* transition: all 0.3s ease-out; */
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      margin: 5px auto;
    }

#toggle.on #one {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(2px) translateY(4px);
}

#toggle.on #two {
  opacity: 0;
}

#toggle.on #three {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(8px) translateY(-10px);
}

#resize {
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  /* transition: all 1s ease-out; */
  display: table;
}

#resize #menu {
  height: 90px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: center;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#resize #menu li {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

#resize li:nth-child(1) {
  margin-top:110px;
}

#resize #menu li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 35px;
  text-decoration: none;  
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}

#resize #menu li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(233, 29, 29);
}



#resize.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.97;
}


@media(max-width: 900px) {
  #toggle {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        margin-top: 15px;
  }

  #toggle .span.scrolled {
    background: #be1b22;
  }

  nav #brand {
        margin-left: 18px;
  }

  #menu a {
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 200;
        font-size: 20px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
  }

  nav #menu {
        display: none;
  }

  nav {
    margin-bottom: -71px;
  }
}
```

html

```
<nav>
                <span id="brand">
                      <a href="home.html"><img class="logo" src="../logo site/imgs/logo-transparent.png" alt="image"></a>
                </span>


                <ul id="menu">
                      <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="Development.html">Development</a></li>
                      <li><a href="fees.html">Fees</a></li>
                      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>

                </ul>

                <div id="toggle">
                      <div class="span" id="one"></div>
                      <div class="span" id="two"></div>
                      <div class="span" id="three"></div>
                </div>
          </nav>
```

I don't know why it flickers but i know it has got to do something with my if statement!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just changed these   `$nav.toggleClass('scrolled');`
to this   `$nav.addClass('scrolled');`
silly me.....